# Predicting changes in values across two time series

Tags: regression, time-series, multilevel-analysis

I have data from an experiment in which participants provided time series data tracking their emotion (on a scale from -10 to 10) after experiencing two discrete stimuli. Data were collected at a rate of once a second for 300 seconds. Thus, every participant has 300 values in time series 1 and 300 values in time series 2. Participants also completed a self-report measure of trait X.

I first examined how values in time series 1 are predicted by `trait X`, by building an MLM regressing `series 1 value` on `trait X`, with the data nested within participants.

Now I am interested in running some tests to examine relationships **between** the time series, specifically:

- a) are `series 1 values` predicted by `trait X` when controlling for values in `series 2 values`?
- b) is the change in `series 1 values` to `series 2 values predicted by` trait X`?

I can envision the non-hierarchical way of modeling these data. I would compute the average of all `series 1 values` for each participant (which I'll call `avg_series_1`), and the average of all `series 2 values` for each participant (which I'll call `avg_series_2`).

- a) using multiple regression, regress `avg_series_1` on `trait X` and `avg_series_2`
- b) compute change in `avg_series_1` and `avg_series_2`, regress the change on `trait X`

However, I would like to perform these analyses hierarchically, and I'm struggling to envision how to build these models. For (a), I could, hypothetically, build a multi-level model in which the DV was `series 1 value`, with `series 2 value` and `trait X` as fixed effects. However, given how my data are structured (see example data below), I'd be predicting `series 1 at second 1` with `series 2 at second 1` and `trait X` (and so on and so on). This doesn't seem right as I wouldn't expect any certain relationship to emerge among data points at the same time point in their respective time series. Rather, I'm wanting to see how controlling for average values in series 2 impacts the effect of `trait X` on average values in series 3.

Are these data better handled non-hierarchically?

I also had the idea to restructure the data by collapsing `series 1 value` and `series 2 value` into the same column (`value`), and create a new variable (called `series #`) representing whether the time series value belongs to series 1 or series 2. I could then use `series #` as a predictor in my model, and perhaps in (a) I'd be looking to see if `trait X` interacts with `series #` to predict `value`. Is this a way of testing (a)? Also, I don't know how to test (b) using this method.

```
pt #  | time  | series 1 value | series 2 value| trait X  
101   |  1 s  |      4         |       3       |   35  
101   |  2 s  |      5         |       3       |   35  
101   |  3 s  |      6         |       2       |   35  
101   |  4 s  |      7         |       1       |   35  
101   |  5 s  |      7         |       1       |   35  
.         .          .                 .            .  
.         .          .                 .            .  
.         .          .                 .            .  
199   |  1 s  |      2         |       -7       |   42  
199   |  2 s  |      1         |       -8       |   42  
199   |  3 s  |      1         |       -9       |   42
```